# JQuery : Replace all text from specific string

Tags: javascript, jquery, regex

My problem is that I want to replace all text that starts from '$amount' into '[dollar]'

Ex. string : "I have $100 and you only have $50"

Result : "I have [dollar] and you only have [dollar]"

Another Ex. : "$testString blah blah blah $anotherString test test"

Result : "[dollar] blah blah blah [dollar] test test"

It affects all string from the body of the page. Thanks!

Comment: Do you need it to be more specific than shown below? i.e. only match $ where it precedes a number?

Comment: Not necessary a number.
If a text that starts from '$' replace it into something else.

see the updated again.
Thank you for your help Aussie.

Answer (score 2):

Use a Regex with global option (`/g`)

```
html = html.replace(/\$/g, "#");
```

You do not say where it needs to be applied though.

e.g. for the entire webpage

```
var html = $('body').html();    
html = html.replace(/\$/g, "#");
$('body').html(html);
```

e.g. for every div (using a function parameter to `html()`):

```
$('div').html(function(i, v){
    return v.replace(/\$/g, "#");
});
```

e.g. for every paragraph (using a function parameter to `html()`):

```
$('p').html(function(i, v){
    return v.replace(/\$/g, "#");
});
```

Update: Match the number amount too:

```
html = html.replace(/\$[0-9.]*/g, "#");
```

**JSFiddle:** http://jsfiddle.net/TrueBlueAussie/kveoxd2e/

Update: Match anything up to next whitespace (e.g. a word):

```
html = html.replace(/\$\w*/g, "[dollar]");
```

**JSFiddle:** http://jsfiddle.net/kveoxd2e/2/

And if you really want cents too... Update: Match anything including cents

```
html = html.replace(/\$(\S)*/g, "[dollar]");
```

**JSFiddle:** http://jsfiddle.net/kveoxd2e/4/

Comment: Sorry, bro. my previous question is not what I want. Kindly check the updated one.

Comment: @aldesabido: Added JSFiddle too for testing.

Comment: @aldesabido: Done. Matches anything up to the next whitespace.

Comment: This won't replace $99.99 for example. http://jsfiddle.net/kveoxd2e/3/ is more precise.

Comment: @ ImreNagy: They did not specify, but that was a simple fix. Have added all versions I can think of now :)

Answer (score 1):

from 0 to infinite    var stringVar = "I have $100 and you only have $50";
    stringVar.replace(/\$/g, "#");

EDIT:

For your updated question you need to alter the regular Expression:

```
stringVar.replace(/\$[0-9]*(\.)?[0-9]+/g, "[dollar]");
```

This should replace any amount, even with decimal points.

You can read the RegEx as:

- $: The character "$"
- [0-9]*: Any number from 0 to infinite or no character at all
- (\.)?: There can be 0 or 1 "."
- [0-9]+: Any number
  from 0 to infinite but at
  least one digit

If you need no check on numbers or even have characters that should be replaced, just use:

```
stringVar.replace(/\$(\S)*/g, "#");
```

- (\S)*: Any non white space character following "$"

Comment: Sorry, bro. my previous question is not what I want. Kindly check the updated one.